# Raw output data frame manipulation in python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-manipulation

Using python 3 I need to process qPCR sequencing raw data outputs by searching for the first occurrence of a user defined string and then making a new data frame using all lines after that string. I am trying to find solutions in the pandas doc but so far unsuccessful.

This is a raw output .csv file that I need to process. (couldn't paste complete csv as exceeds character limit, this is lines 40-50 and am hoping this text is useful?). I need to tell pandas to create a new data frame that 1. starts at the line containg the first occurance of str("Sample Name") with that line as header and containing all lines following. And then 2., only including columns ("Sample Name"), ("Target Name"), ("CT").

Could someone please help me so that I can use python to help me analyze biological data?
Many thanks,
Luke

```
40,Quantification Cycle Method,Ct,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

41,Signal Smoothing On,true,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

42,Stage where Melt Analysis is performed,Stage3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

43,Stage/ Cycle where Ct Analysis is performed,"Stage2, Step2",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

44,User Name,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

45,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

46,Well,Well Position,Omit,Sample Name,Target Name,Task,Reporter,Quencher,Quantity,Quantity Mean,SE,RQ,RQ Min,RQ Max,CT,Ct Mean,Ct SD,Delta Ct,Delta Ct Mean,Delta Ct SD,Delta Ct SE,Delta Delta Ct,Automatic Ct Threshold,Ct Threshold,Automatic Baseline,Baseline Start,Baseline End,Amp Status,Comments,Cq Conf,CQCONF,HIGHSD,OUTLIERRG,Tm1,Tm2,Tm3,Tm4

47,1,A1,False,WT1,AtTubulin,UNKNOWN,SYBR,None,,,,,,,23.357698440551758,23.4766845703125,0.5336655378341675,,,,,,True,20959.612776965325,True,3,17,Amp,,0.9588544573203085,N,Y,N,81.40960693359375,,,

48,2,A2,False,WT1,AtTubulin,UNKNOWN,SYBR,None,,,,,,,24.05980110168457,23.4766845703125,0.5336655378341675,,,,,,True,20959.612776965325,True,3,15,Amp,,0.9592687354496955,N,Y,N,81.40960693359375,,,

49,3,A3,False,WT1,AtTubulin,UNKNOWN,SYBR,None,,,,,,,23.012556076049805,23.4766845703125,0.5336655378341675,,,,,,True,20959.612776965325,True,3,16,Amp,,0.9592714462250367,N,Y,N,81.40960693359375,,,

50,4,A4,False,fla11fla12-1,AtTubulin,UNKNOWN,SYBR,None,,,,,,,23.803699493408203,24.419523239135742,0.5669151544570923,,,,,,True,20959.612776965325,True,3,17,Amp,,0.9671570584141241,N,Y,N,81.40960693359375,,,
```

This is the code that I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_excel ("2019-02-27_161601 AtWAKL8 different version expressions.xls", sheet_name='Results').fillna(0)

data.to_csv('df1' + '.csv', index=True)

df1 = pd.read_csv ("df1.csv")
```

Comment: I just need to select the line I want that contains the string "Sample Name" and make a new data frame including that line as the header and every line following. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You are having trouble with quoting.
2. `grep` is a better fit for .csv files rather than .xlsx

You are forking off a shell subprocess with a filename argument,
without correctly quoting the spaces in the filename.
It would be simplest to rename it, turning spaces into dashes,
e.g. 2019-02-27_161601-AtWAKL8-different-version-expressions.xls
As it stands, you are trying to `grep` the string "Position"
from a file named `2019-02-27_161601`,
and from a 2nd file named `AtWAKL8`,
a 3rd named `different`, and so on,
which is unlikely to work.

An .xlsx spreadsheet is not the line-oriented
text format that `grep` expects.
You will be happier if you export or Save As .csv format within Excel,
or if you execute `data.to_csv('expressions.csv')`

Comment: Well, you are free to quote it correctly. Probably better to use the default of `shell=False` and supply a list, so `argv[2]` will have the necessary spaces. Or have python do the matching, rather than `grep`.

Comment: 1. The file type and name is the native output of hi J_H thanks very much for your answer. The device being used exports the data in a multi-sheet .xls format. Is there a solution where python will find spaces in the file name and replace them with a dash? 2. I am trying to automate the retrieval of the required data frame from raw data output. The data report that is required is on sheet 3 of the native .xls workbook. Is there a way to tell python to go to sheet three and savecsv of that sheet?

Comment: (1.) Quote correctly, or use an API that doesn't involve quoting, so spaces won't be troublesome. I suggested using a list with `shell=False`. (2.) To read the third sheet, refer to the `sheet_name` parameter of the method you're calling: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel